# Execute specs2 examples wrapped in function

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

How can I execute all tests for a spec2 Specification in a wrapper function?

ex:

```
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {

    wrapAll(example) = {
        // wrap it in a session, for example.
        with(someSession){
            example()
        }
    }

    "The 'Hello world' string" should {
      "contain 11 characters" in {
        "Hello world" must have size(11)
      }
      "start with 'Hello'" in {
        "Hello world" must startWith("Hello")
      }
      "end with 'world'" in {
        "Hello world" must endWith("world")
      }
    }
  }
```

So, each of these 3 tests should be executed inside the

> with(someSession){...

When using ScalaTest, I could do that overriding *withFixture*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like [`AroundExample`](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#BeforeExample):

```
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification with AroundExample {
  def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = inWhateverSession(t)
  ...
}
```

Or an [implicit context object](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Implicit+context):

```
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {
  implicit object sessionContext = new Around {
    def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = inWhateverSession(t)
  }
  ...
}
```

Depending on exactly what you need to do, some combination of the `Before`, `BeforeAfter`, or `Outside` contexts (and their `Example` counterparts) might fit more appropriately.